# Margin top is not working in IE 6

Tags: html, css, background

my code

```
<div id="header">
<div id="header_top">KIDS'<br>ZONE</div>
</div>
```

css

```
#header{
        width:1024px;
    height:150px;
    background:url('../images/Orange.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:1024px 150px;
}
#header_top
{
    background:#842DCE;
    width:125px;
    height:70px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-top:-20px;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:25px;
    padding-top:5px;
    opacity:1;
    font-weight:bold;

}
```

my result in other browsers except IE

[image]

In IE

[image]

Might be it is very simple,bt i am struggling ,please help me

Comment: try with setting `position` attribute

Comment: please post your code in jsfiddle.net

Comment: No, tell the people still using IE6 that they need to upgrade. Seriously! See http://www.ie6countdown.com/.

Comment: yea, please give me a solution.Is there any css tricks for this?

Comment: why are you still using IE6......

Comment: yea u r right ,I want  to stop using Internet Explorer 6. Thank u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should seriously ditch IE6 support. Even Microsoft are advocating this, as per their [IE6 Countdown](http://www.ie6countdown.com/) site:

> There are many benefits of upgrading to a newer version of Internet Explorer – improved speed, tabbed browsing, and better privacy settings to name a few.
>
> The web has changed significantly over the past 10 years. The browser has evolved to adapt to new web technologies, and the latest versions of Internet Explorer help protect you from new attacks and threats.
>
> We recommend that Internet Explorer 6 users upgrade to a newer version of Internet Explorer for a safer browsing experience.

At some point, you really just have to move on. Few people explicitly support Netscape Navigator or the Lynx browser nowadays, or code in Fortran, BCPL or RCA1802 assembler language. And for good reason.

And, on the off-chance that you're one of those organisations that still insists on using IE6 because it "just works" (Hah!), the *Educate* section on that link above has some resources to help you out.

Answer (score 3):

CSS

```
    #header{background-color:#FF6600; height:150px; margin-top:100px; position:relative; overflow:visible;}
#header_top{width:100px; height:50px; position:absolute; top:-20px; left:25px; background-color:#CC0099;}
```

HTML

```
    <div id="header">
         <div id="header_top"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign position:absolute to the child element

eg:

```
<style>
#header {width:220px; height:150px; background-color:blue; margin:100px; position:absolute}
#header_top {width:200px; height:130px; background-color:yellow; text-align:justify; margin-top:-50px; position:absolute}
</style>
```

And here is a link for further reference :) [Definitive Guide to Taming the IE6 Beast](http://stylisticweb.com/design-tutorials/15-ie6-bugs-and-simple-solutions) .
*If possible stop supporting ie6 .*